# Heapify in C++ STL?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am looking for a function that does Heapify but seems that there is no efficient function directly from C++ STL.

A heapify function as defined in CLRS text book will take in an element location i, assuming the left and right sub trees of i are both heaps, and make the tree rooted at i become a heap, and complexity is log(n).

Given a heap in [first, last), I would like to remove the first element, replace it with another element, and maintain the heap property. To achieve this, we only need to call heapify(first) once, traverse down the heap once, with log(n) complexity.

STL has pop_heap and push_heap functions, and it could achieve the goal by first call pop_heap and push_heap, but pop_heap maintains heap property, and push_heap also maintains heap property, this infers two traverse in the heap. Even though the overall complexity is still log(n), it is not efficient. We do not need to maintain the heap property after removing the first element.

Any good idea besides writing my own heapify function?

Comment: *Any good idea besides writing my own heapify function?* Do not worry about the performance impact until you have written the easiest code possible and found through testing and experimentation that optimization here is necessary. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Patrick87 This statement doesn’t really apply to established algorithm building blocks. At all. In fact, applying it here is nonsense and just parrots a phrase without understanding it.

Comment: make_heap is linear time, it basically does heapify multiple times, with no assumption on the existing array property. Note that heapify assumes that the sub trees are heaps.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sure it does. It would take him 5 minutes to implement it as described and test to see if performance is satisfactory. In my experience, doubling the time taken by the heapify operation is not going to be the bottleneck in your application. Perhaps your experience is different.

Comment: I will use pop_heap and push_heap for now. Just curious if there is any way to do better.

Comment: If you exclude maintain heap property on `pop_heap` step, what makes you think its still possible to re-establish order with log(n) complexity ?

Answer (score 4):

The standard library has no `swimDown` or `swimUp` functions (as described in algorithms books, anyway [std::make_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) achieves heapify on a vector in linear time (details [here](http://marcodiiga.github.io/kth-order-statistic/)). You can modify the element you want and then call `make_heap` on the vector.

```
int main()
{
  int myints[] = {10,20,30,5,15};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+5);

  std::make_heap (v.begin(),v.end());
  std::cout << "initial max heap   : " << v.front() << '\n';

  // Modify first element
  v[0] = 10;
  std::make_heap(v.begin(),v.end());
  std::cout << "after modification max heap   : " << v.front() << '\n';
}
```

Another solution is to

1. Push the modified element to the back of the vector
2. Call `pop_heap` which will exchange the first and the last elements and reheapify (a single `swimDown`)
3. Pop the former first element from the back

This might probably be even more efficient (if only for the number of comparisons) needed

```
int main()
{
  int myints[] = {10,20,30,5,15};
  std::vector<int> v(myints,myints+5);

  std::make_heap (v.begin(),v.end());
  std::cout << "initial max heap   : " << v.front() << '\n';

  v.push_back(10);
  std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); // Takes 30 out of the heap and swims 10 down
  v.pop_back(); // Drops 30

  std::cout << "after modification max heap   : " << v.front() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Its O(n) versus 2 log(n). Not good tradeoff i think.

Comment: The second solution works and is efficient!