# Heapify in logarithmic time using the C++ standard library

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, heap

I have a heap using `std::make_heap`:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,5,9,20,3};
std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
```

now I update the heap by changing one random element:

```
v[3] = 35;
```

Is there a way in standard library in to adjust heap again in `O(log n)` time where `n` is size of container. Basically I am looking for heapify function. I know what element has been changed.

I understand that `std::make_heap` is `O(n log n)` time. I have also gone through duplicate question but that is different in sense that it is changing max element. For that solution is already given of `O(log n)` complexity in that question.

I am trying to change any random element within heap.

Comment: If you intend to make regular changes to your heap, I'd probably use `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heapify in C++ STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213377/heapify-in-c-stl)

Comment: the complexity of `make_heap` is only linear, so just call it again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do it yourself:

```
void modify_heap_element(std::vector<int> &heap, size_t index, int value)
{
    //while value is too large for its position, bubble up
    while(index > 0 && heap[(index-1)>>1] < value)
    {
        size_t parent = (index-1)>>1;
        heap[index]=heap[parent];
        index = parent;
    }
    //while value is too large for its position sift down
    for (;;)
    {
        size_t left=index*2+1;
        size_t right=left+1;
        if (left >= heap.size())
            break;
        size_t bigchild = (right >= heap.size() || heap[right] < heap[left] ?
                           left : right );
        if (!(value < heap[bigchild]))
           break;
        heap[index]=heap[bigchild];
        index = bigchild;
    }
    heap[index] = value;
}
```

Comment: effectively I can assume that standard algorithm handles this way as shown, i can manually modify as well. I think request for standard algorithm for heapify can be made.

Comment: @code707 this is not in the standard library because there just aren't a lot of use cases for this function.  I don't know what you're working on, but if you you need a heap with modifiable elements for Dijkstra's algorithm or something, then this doesn't quite cut it.   In order to find the element to modify, you'd normally need back-pointers from the values to their positions in the heap.  In that case you can't use any of the STL fuctions, and the above function would need to be modified to maintain those back-pointers as it shifted elements around.

Answer (score 5):

If we look closer at your statement:

> now I disturb heap by changing one **random** element of heap.

For heapifying in `O(log n)` you can only directly "disturb" the *back* or the *front* of the vector (which corresponds somehow to inserting or deleting an element).  In these cases, (re)heapification can be then achieved by means of the [`std::push_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [`std::pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) algorithms, which take logarithmic running time.

That is, the back:

```
v.back() = 35;
std::push_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); // heapify in O(log n)
```

or the front:

```
v.front() = 35;

// places the front at the back
std::pop_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); // O(log n)
// v.back() is now 35, but it does not belong to the heap anymore

// make the back belong to the heap again
std::push_heap(v.begin(), v.end()); // O(log n)
```

Otherwise you need to reheapify the whole vector with [`std::make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), which takes linear running time.

---

#### Summary

It's not possible to modify an arbitrary element of the heap and achieve the heapification in logarithmic running time with the standard library (i.e., the function templates `std::push_heap` and `std::pop_heap`). However, you can always implement the heap's *swim* and *sink* operations by yourself in order to heapify in logarithmic running time.

Comment: so effectively, it is not possible in longN, worst case is linear time.

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing this problem of wanting an "updateable heap" as well. However, in the end, instead of coding a custom updateable heap or anything like that, I solved it a bit differently.

To maintain access to the best element without needing to explicitly go through the heap, you can use versioned wrappers of the elements that you want to order. Each unique, true element has a version counter, which is increased every time the element gets changed. Each wrapper inside the heap then carries a version of the element, being the version at the time the wrapper was created:

```
struct HeapElemWrapper
{
    HeapElem * e;

    size_t version;        
    double priority;

    HeapElemWrapper(HeapElem * elem)
     : e(elem), version(elem->currentVersion), priority(0.0)
    {}

    bool upToDate() const
    {
        return version == e->currentVersion;
    }

    // operator for ordering with heap / priority queue:
    // smaller error -> higher priority
    bool operator<(const HeapElemWrapper & other) const
    {
        return this->priority> other.priority;
    }
};
```

When popping the topmost element from the heap, you can then simply check this wrapper element to see if it's up-to-date with the original. If not, simply dispose it and pop the next one. This method is quite efficient, and I have it seen in other applications as well. The only thing you need to take care of is that you do a pass over the heap to clean it up from outdated elements, from time to time (say, every 1000 insertions or so).

Comment: iif updated element is topmost element, how will it move to to top?

Comment: not sure if I get the question - if the element is already on top, what's the problem? in any case, the idea is that you insert a copy into the heap, at the appropriate position, using the up-to-date version of the element, that new heap element will then automatically bubble to the correct position, without the need to re-structure the heap due to some modified element in the middle

Answer (score 2):

[It's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668286/8012646) to modify an arbitrary element of the heap in logarithmic running time without violating the heap property by just using the function templates `std::pop_heap()` and `std::push_heap()` that the standard library provides.

However, you can define your own STL-like function template, `set_heap_element()`, for that purpose:

```
template<typename RandomIt, typename T, typename Cmp>
void set_heap_element(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, RandomIt pos, T value, Cmp cmp)
{
    const auto n = last - first;
    *pos = std::move(value); // replace previous value

    auto i = pos - first;
    using std::swap;

    // percolate up
    while (i > 0) { // non-root node
        auto parent_it = first + (i-1)/2;

        if (cmp(*pos, *parent_it))
            break; // parent node satisfies the heap-property 

        swap(*pos, *parent_it); // swap with parent
        pos = parent_it;
        i = pos - first;
    }

    // percolate down
    while (2*i + 1 < n) { // non-leaf node, since it has a left child
        const auto lidx = 2*i + 1, ridx = 2*i + 2;

        auto lchild_it = first + lidx; 
        auto rchild_it = ridx < n? first + ridx: last;

        auto it = pos;
        if (cmp(*it, *lchild_it))
            it = lchild_it;
        if (rchild_it != last && cmp(*it, *rchild_it))
            it = rchild_it;

        if (pos == it)
            break; // node satisfies the heap-property

        swap(*pos, *it); // swap with child
        pos = it;
        i = pos - first;
    }
}
```

Then, you can provide the following simplified overload of `set_heap_element()` for a *max heap*:

```
#include <functional> // std::less

template<typename RandomIt, typename T>
void set_heap_element(RandomIt first, RandomIt last, RandomIt pos, T value) {
    return set_heap_element(first, last, pos, value, std::less<T>{});
}
```

This overload uses a `std::less<T>` object as the comparison function object for the original function template.

---

#### Example

In your *max-heap* example, `set_heap_element()` could be used as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,5,9,20,3};
std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());

// set 4th element to 35 in O(log n)
set_heap_element(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin() + 3, 35);
```

You could use `std::is_heap()`, which takes linear time, whenever you want to check whether the *max-heap property* is still satisfied by `v` after setting an element with the `set_heap_element()` function template above:

```
assert(std::is_heap(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

#### What about *min* heaps?

You can achieve the same for a *min heap* by passing a `std::greater<int>` object as the last argument of the function calls to `std::make_heap()`, `set_heap_element()` and `std::is_heap()`:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,5,9,20,3};
// create a min heap
std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>{});

// set 4th element to 35 in O(log n)
set_heap_element(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin() + 3, 35, std::greater<int>{});

// is the min-heap property satisfied?
assert(std::is_heap(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<int>{}));
```